# Argument passed in must be a Buffer or string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters while using OR condition in node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to fetch data from database by `_id` and `ownerId` so I gave `OR` condition, but getting this error

```
Argument passed in must be a Buffer or string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

My code as follow

```js
var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;


const getDetailById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    let detail = await Task.find(
      { $or: [{ ownerId: id }, { _id: ObjectId(id) }] }
    ).populate("shop");
    } catch (err) {
    sendError(401, "Cannot get detail by given id", err.message, req, res);
  }
};
```

here I can get data from database by passing `_id` which is 24 character but when I tried to fetch data by `ownerId` its shows me this error:

```
Argument passed in must be a Buffer or string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

My output look like this

```json
 {
      "_id": "61483aa5e6dcd5bb6b2c9c58",
      "ownerId": "b0jytaonktsc5ghf",
      "ownerName": "check demo",
      "ownerDescription": "Testing purpose",
      "shop": {
        "_id": "61483aa5e6dcd5bb6b2c9c55",
        "shopName": "Aakash",
        "shopPlace": "Mumbai",
        "__v": 0
      },
      
      "createdAt": "2021-09-20T07:39:17.528Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-09-20T07:39:17.528Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
```

and this is my Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqid = require("uniqid");

const ownerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ownerId: {
      type: String,
      default: uniqid(),
      unique: true,
    },
    OwnerName: {
      type: String,           
    },
    taskTag: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
    onwerDescription: {
      type: String,
    },       
    shop: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "peoples",
      default: null,
    },    
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const owner = mongoose.model("task", ownerSchema);

module.exports = owner;
```

Comment: You don't need to pass new with ObjectId. Also, have you made the ownerId type: ObjectId?

Comment: even after removing new I am getting same error @ApoorvaChikara

Comment: The issue seems to be with `ownerId`. Can you add the mongoose schema for it?

Comment: yes sure @ApoorvaChikara

Comment: Hi @ApoorvaChikaraI have updated my Post

Comment: Your `ownerId ` is of type String, it is not ObjectId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

- `ObjectId` has exactly 24 hex characters or string of 12 bytes
- `uniqid` library that you use for generating `ownerId` generates 18 byte unique id

## Reason

As you see the format of these 2 is not compatible. So what happened is this:

1. You try to query database based on the value that `uniqid()` generated
2. The second parameter of `$or` will try to generate `ObjectId` based on that value, and since the format is not compatible with `ObjectId` format, it will throw the error that it is invalid format of the `ObjectId`

## Solution

You can change the `uniqid` library with the native Node `crypto` library to generate 24 hex characters string of 12 bytes, that will be compatible with `ObjectId` format. Since it is native package, you don't need to install it, you can just import it and use it. Now you can also remove `uniqid` package from you project and decrease the number of dependencies.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const ownerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ownerId: {
      type: String,
      default: crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex'),
      unique: true
  },
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the call of `ObjectId(id)` because it can not handle the input of an `ownerId` string as soon as you are passing the ownerId.

The cleanest solution (in my opinion) would be to change the type of `ownerId` to `ObjectId` as well:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqid = require("uniqid");

const ownerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ownerId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      default: mongoose.ObjectId(),
      unique: true,
    },
    OwnerName: {
      type: String,           
    },
...
```

Or to handle the different inputs like:

```js
var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;

const getDetailById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  let filter = [{ ownerId: id }]
  try {
    const _id = ObjectId(id);
    filter.push({ _id })
  } catch () {
    // Do nothing
  }

  try {
    let detail = await Task.find(
      { $or: filter }
    ).populate("shop");
  } catch (err) {
    sendError(401, "Cannot get detail by given id", err.message, req, res);
  }
};
```

PS: Do not forget to perform some input validation! Never trust user input ;)

Comment: not helping its still showing me same error

Comment: Which one of them? I mean, if you have chosen the first one, you can not use old values for ownerId of course, as they are not a valid objectId

Comment: 2nd one not working and I cant use first one